# Maximum value of |Z|

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima

Question :What is the maximum value of $\lvert z\rvert$ when $z$ satisfies the condition $\lvert z+\frac{2}{z}\rvert=2$

My try: By removing modulus, and simplifying as $-2<z+\frac{2}{z}<2$, I am not getting the required answer. Someone please help.

Comment: $z$ is a complex number, your inequality makes no sense at all.

Comment: -2<z+2/z doesnt make sense for complex z

Comment: Have edited the question, Z is not a complex number.

Comment: Please let me know how can I proceed from there?

Comment: There is no such real $z$.

Comment: How can you say that? My book shows the answer as $3^{0.5}+1$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cz%2B2%2Fz%7C%3D2) offers $z=\pm\sqrt{\frac32}\pm i\sqrt{\frac52}$ with $|z|=2$

Comment: I don't see things getting any clearer I'm sorry, someone with a concrete approach is welcomed.

Comment: @user38227 how does that satisfy the condition on $z$ if $z$ is a real number? (that answer makes perfect sense if $z$ is a complex number though)

Comment: @user38227 You can confirm then with a calculator that your textbook is incorrect. $3^{0.5} + 1 + \frac{2}{3^{0.5} +1} \approx 3.46$

Comment: Anyway: here's the answer to the correct question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853992/max-and-min-value-of-z-in-leftz-frac2z-right-2

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml